# ActiveRecord SUM includes more objects in the calculation than it supplies the same query without sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I faced today a problem that leads me in a gotcha of **ActiveRecord** use.

ActiveRecord returns for a specific query (with **includes**) certain amount of objects in an **ActiveRelation** object.
If you chain on the same ActiveRecord query `sum(:attribute)`, it includes more objects in the calculated result. To describe what I mean here my example:

Environment:
ActiveRecord 4.2.3
Postgres 9.3.5

DB-structure:

Order has_many items

My query:

```
@orders = Order.includes(:items).where('orders.created_at >= ? AND orders.created_at <= ?', date_from, date_to)
```

The produced SQL-Query:

```
SELECT orders.* FROM order_containers WHERE orders.created_at >= '2015-08-11' AND orders.created_at <= '2015-08-17 23:59:59.999999';
```

The mentioned query returns e.g. 20 orders. As you can see, the **includes** doesn't play any rule in the query. And if I **sum** the **price** for the result, in ruby:

```
@orders.to_a.sum(&:price)
```

it returns 20.00

The same ActiveRecord query with **SUM**:

```
Order.includes(:items).where('orders.created_at >= ? AND orders.created_at <= ?', date_from, date_to).sum(:price)
```

it returns 45.00

It produces a different SQL statment:

```
SELECT SUM(orders.price_eur) FROM orders LEFT OUTER JOIN line_items ON items.order_container_id = orders.id WHERE orders.created_at >= '2015-08-11' AND orders.created_at <= '2015-08-17 23:59:59.999999'
```

The summed orders in this case are much more because the produced SQL-query includes the same order more than one time (**because of Join**). Every order has one or more items what leads to much more orders (**duplicates**) than the query without the **Left Outer Join**.

I hope this can help you avoid this gotcha.

nabinabou

Comment: This is interesting but it's also not a question...

Comment: Yes it is not really a question. I hoped I would get an explanation for something that I misunderstand.

Comment: Do you find a way to calculate this sum only with SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

`includes` is generally used for [eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations). Why don't you replace it with `joins`?

Comment: My goal is eager loading, as you can see in the conditions.

Comment: It doesn't change any thing if you use joins or includes. The result stays the same. If I used joins I would expect something like this.